# Display panel on a calling page (WP7)

Tags: windows-phone-7, controls, panel

I want to display a small panel in front of a page in windows phone 7

Once a page called method, a panel should appear above the page on the center of the screen

I created a class that extends panel and I stopped on how can I make this form appear on front of any calling page

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [MessagePrompt](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MessagePrompt), a control from [Coding4Fun](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/).

Place your panel code in the MessagePrompt UserControl and call it in every page you want.

Comment: how can make the tick button in the messageprompt become in visible
i don't want it